# Show only one post on custom post type archive

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

First of all thanks for your time!

Im trying to show only the last element of my Custom post type (CPT) in the archive page, I tried it but it is showing the las Post, not the last CPT element, I dont know what im doing wrong but I think is this line:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1'); ?>
```

here you can see my code.

Would you be able to help me? Thanks in advance.

https://github.com/cmr96/WordPress/blob/master/archive-cpt_proyectos.php

Comment: Why are you using a custom query on the archive? You should be using the standard loop: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#using-the-loop

Comment: Thanks Jacob, Im new to WP development, I used the default one but I couldnt select only one post, and I dont know other way to select only one, would you be able to do it as you said but selecting only 1 element?

Comment: To limit the number of posts in an archive to 1, you need to use the [`pre_get_posts` filter](https://wpshout.com/practical-uses-pre_get_posts/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please thoroughly read the `WP_Query` docs, especially that [part about post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters). Means you need to pass the query the post type you want to query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

---

Even better it would be to simply override the existing query for that archive page by hooking into [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). This will for example also adjust the pagination accordingly. Place this in your `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Override the main query on a custom post type archive.
 *
 * @param \WP_Query $wp_query
 */
function wpse_337567( WP_Query $wp_query ) {

    // Only check this on the main query.
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'my_custom_post_type' ) && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_337567' );
```